# 404 error when trying to edit any plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I try to click on Edit in the Plugins Section (on any plugin) , all I'm getting is a 404 error on the so called plugins.

http://www.example.com/nt/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php?file=debug-this/debug-this.php

-> returns 404.

Any idea? I tried Saving Permalinks or even check for the location , it all fits.

Comment: what are the most recent changes you made to the site which started to cause this error?

Comment: no changes , literally the fresh install has the same problems

Comment: can you share us the URL?

Comment: it could be your .htaccess or php.ini settings